# How can I compile a Perl script inside a running Perl session?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that takes user input and creates another script that will be run at a later date.  I'm currently going through and writing tests for these scripts and one of the tests that I would like to perform is checking if the generated script compiles successfully (e.g. `perl -c <script>`.)  Is there a way that I can have Perl perform a compile on the generated script without having to spawn another Perl process?  I've tried searching for answers, but searches just turn up information about compiling Perl scripts into executable programs.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile" exactly? Check for errors? Or execute it?

Comment: @user1215106 Check for errors, not actually run it.  I want to make sure that script won't fail due to syntax errors when run later.

Comment: Do you create the code dynamically in your script?

Comment: @user1215106 Yes, it follows a basic framework, but there are dynamically generated sections and subroutines in it.

Comment: how dynamic is the generation of the Perl script? Could you template it ala HTML generation or is it more complex than that?

Comment: There is no compilation for perl scripts. `-c` option does syntax checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute dynamically generated code, use `eval` function:

```
my $script = join /\n/, <main::DATA>;
eval($script);   # 3

__DATA__

my $a = 1;
my $b = 2;
print $a+$b, "\n";
```

However if you want to just compile or check syntax, then you will not be able to do it within same Perl session.

Function `syntax_ok` from library [Test::Strict](http://search.cpan.org/~pdenis/Test-Strict-0.14/lib/Test/Strict.pm#syntax_ok%28_$file_%5B,_$text%5D_%29) run a syntax check by running `perl -c` with an external perl interpreter, so I assume there is no internal way.

Only work-around that may work for you would be:

```
my $script = join /\n/, <main::DATA>; 
eval('return;' . $script); 
warn $@ if $@;   # syntax error at (eval 1) line 3, near "1
                 # my "

__DATA__ 

my $a = 1
my $b = 2; 
print $a+$b, "\n";
```

In this case, you will be able to check for compilation error(s) using `$@`, however because the first line of the code is `return;`, it will not execute.

---

*Note: Thanks to user [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) for helpfull chat and code correction.*

Comment: evaluating `exit`, though, will exit the calling program. Maybe use `return` or wrap the code in `if (0) { ... }`

Comment: `perl -e 'eval("exit 1;/more valid code/;");print "hey I was right!"' || echo 'Oh wait, I guess mob was right.'`

Comment: your code works because the eval'd string doesn't compile. If the eval was successful, your program would exit.

Answer (score 6):

Compiling a script has a lot of side-effects. It results in subs being defined. It results in modules being executed. etc. If you simply want to test whether something compiles, you *want* a separate interpreter. It's the only way to be sure that one testing one script doesn't cause later tests to give false positives or false negatives.

Answer (score 1):

Won't something like this work for you ?

```
open(FILE,"perl -c generated_script.pl 2>&1 |");
@output=<FILE>;
if(join('',@output)=~/syntax OK/)
{
   printf("No Problem\n");
}
close(FILE);
```

Comment: rather than piping, is there any reason not to use backticks?

Comment: I love you! Thank you so much. This specific solution of piping really helped in my specific case!

Answer (score 1):

See [`Test::Compile`](http://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aCompile) module, particularly `pl_file_ok()` function.